# Trouble updating Doc in Firestore with React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to edit a document in my firestore db. I get an error i cant figure out.
`Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'va', but it was: a custom Fh object`

Im passing in an Object to the updateDoc function using the spread operator.

```
const saveEvent = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log(isChecked)
    const checked = [];
    isChecked.map((item, index) => {
        if (item === true) {
            checked.push(index + 1)
        }
    })
    console.log(checked)
    const newEvent = {
        id: tempEvent.id,
        title: popupEventTitle,
        description: popupEventDescription,
        start: popupEventDate[0].toString(),
        end: popupEventDate[1].toString(),
        allDay: popupEventAllDay,
        status: popupEventStatus,
        color: selectedColor,
        resource: checked
    };
    if (isEdit) {
        // update the event in the list
        const index = myEvents.findIndex(x => x.id === tempEvent.id);
        const newEventList = [...myEvents];

        newEventList.splice(index, 1, newEvent);
        console.log(newEventList)
        setMyEvents(newEventList);

  // ISSUE IS IN THE UpdateEvent function
        const UpdateEvent = async () => {

            const userRef = collection(database, 'events');
            const q = query(userRef, where('id', '==', `${tempEvent.id}`));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(newEvent)
                updateDoc(doc, {
                    ...newEvent,
                });
            })
        }
        UpdateEvent()

    } else {
        // add the new event to the list
        setMyEvents([...myEvents, newEvent]);
        const getEvents = async () => {
            try {
                const docRef = await addDoc(collection(database, "events"), {
                    id: tempEvent.id,
                    title: popupEventTitle,
                    description: popupEventDescription,
                    start: new Date(popupEventDate[0]),
                    end: new Date(popupEventDate[1]),
                    allDay: popupEventAllDay,
                    status: popupEventStatus,
                    color: selectedColor,
                    resource: checked
                });
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
            }
        }
        //console.log(newEvent)
        getEvents()
    }
    setSelectedDate(popupEventDate[0]);
    setOpen(false);
}, [isEdit, myEvents, popupEventAllDay, popupEventDate, popupEventDescription, popupEventStatus, popupEventTitle, tempEvent, selectedColor, isChecked]);
```

Im not sure whats wrong, and googling the issue gives me little to work with. I cant find anything about `Expected type 'va', but it was: a custom Fh object` anywhere. Not even in the documentation..

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Ater logging doc.query i noticed a small Va on the top of the document. Also a small "$h" when logging doc Anyone know anything more about that?
Screenshots:
[image: Logging doc]
[image: Logging doc.query]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs when you're updating a document with incorrect document reference. You should use `ref` property to get the document reference to properly update the document on your foreach loop. See snippet below:

```
const UpdateEvent = async () => {

  const userRef = collection(database, 'events');
  const q = query(userRef, where('id', '==', `${tempEvent.id}`));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(newEvent)
      // Here. You shouldn't use the doc object itself.
      // You must use the `reference` property to get the document reference to update to.
      updateDoc(doc.ref, {
          ...newEvent,
      });
  })
}
UpdateEvent()
```

For more information, you may checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference).

Comment: Yes! Exactly right. So hard to find any info on that particular error message.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

// ISSUE IS IN THE UpdateEvent function
const UpdateEvent = async () => {
const userRef = collection(database, 'events');
*const q = query(userRef, where('id', '==',`${tempEvent.id}`));*
**if you are using 'where' claouse then you will always get one doc**
***const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);***
**const doc = await getDocs(q);** ***try this***
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
console.log(newEvent)
updateDoc(doc, {
...newEvent,
});
})
}
UpdateEvent()

Answer (score 0):

***Try this***
// ISSUE IS IN THE UpdateEvent function
const UpdateEvent = async () => {

```
        const userRef = collection(database, 'events');
        const q = query(userRef, where('id', '==', `${tempEvent.id}`));
        const doc = await getDocs(q);
        //querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(newEvent)
            updateDoc(doc, {
                ...newEvent,
            //});
        })
    }
    UpdateEvent()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. But did not solve the issue.. I updated the post with some photos of my console.log() any idea what the "Va" and "$h" is?
Seems im not allowed to edit them for some reason?

Comment: Share your firebase "rules"  Or test it by updating :- rules_version = '2';
2
service firebase.storage {
3
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
4
    match /{allPaths=**} {
5
      allow read, write;
6
    }
7
  }
8
}

Comment: Im using testing rules.. rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 9, 23);
    }
  }
}